# triangle inquality question

Tags: real-analysis

If $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two given contstants such that $|x|\le C_1$ and $|y|\le C_2$ find a constant $C$ such that $|x-y|\le C$.

Would I use the second form of triangle inequality :

$|a-b| \geq ||a|-|b||$ and in particular $|a-b| \geq |a|-|b|$

and how would I begin it?

Comment: Is C = C1+C2 good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$|x-y|=|x+(-y)|\le |x|+|-y|=|x|+|y|\le C_1+C_2.$$